# mysql `sounds like` not returning all the correct/expected results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called key_words :

```
id        | keyword
-------------------
1         | dream
2         | dreams
3         | draw
4         | sudipto
5         | sudipta
```

when I execute these queries :

1. `select keyword from key_words where keyword sounds like 'dream'`
2. `select keyword from key_words where keyword sounds like 'drea'`
3. `select keyword from key_words where keyword sounds like 'sudipto'`

   I'm expecting these results respectively:

```
1. keyword
----------
   dream
   dreams
   draw (maybe)

2. keyword
----------
   draw
   dream
   dreams

3. keyword
----------
   sudipto
   Sudipta
```

but I got these results respectively:

```
1. keyword
----------
   dream

2. keyword
----------
   draw

3. keyword
----------
   sudipto
   Sudipta
```

Why isn't `sounds like` returning the expected results and what can I do to get the desired results?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. You haven't read the manual for sounds like: `This is the same as SOUNDEX(expr1) = SOUNDEX(expr2).` Try the soundex values and you will see where they match and where they don't.

Comment: While fun, I think SOUNDEX is almost completely useless for anything practical. In this instance, a Levenshtein test might be more rewarding

Comment: @Strawberry Levenshtein is too heavy since I have a large table

Comment: So your choices are presently a heavy function versus a non-working one. It might be best to handle this in application code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find something like

```
1. keyword
----------
   dream
   dreams
   draw (maybe)

2. keyword
----------
   draw
   dream
   dreams

3. keyword
----------
   sudipto
   Sudipta
```

you can use regular expressions or write something like this:

```
select keyword from key_words where keyword sounds like 'dream_'

select keyword from key_words where keyword sounds like 'sudipt_'
```

i dont know what to tell you about the middle row, but only:

```
select keyword from key_words where keyword sounds like 'dr%'
```

The problem is in **sounds like**. 
I think that you saw the explanation about it. 
*MySQL SOUNDS LIKE is used as SOUNDEX(expr) = SOUNDEX(expr) to retrieve strings sounds* similar. If it is important to use it follow the link [SOUNDEX](https://w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-soundex-function.php). As for me, i think that this way is unreliable.

It might help you. Good luck!